# Math function in Java doesn't provide an exact answer

Tags: java, math

I've got the following piece of code:

```
rotation[0][0] = Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(angle));
```

I'm trying to convert an angle from radians to degrees and find the *cosine* of that value.

However, in `toDegrees`' function descriptor, it says that the degree conversion isn't exact.

`Cos90 (deg)` should be equal to 0, but my above snippet gives `-0.29951`...

How am I supposed to get an 'exact' answer? (I.e. get `Cos90 = 0`).

Comment: Doesn't cos() work on angles instead of degrees?

Comment: @Thomas means radians instead of degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use radians for `Math.cos`:

```
rotation[0][0] = Math.cos(angle); // if angle is in radians
```

or

```
rotation[0][0] = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)); // if angle is in degrees
```

Comment: I realised my input is actually degrees (90). So I used the toRadians method, and I'm still getting the same answer as before?

Comment: You recompiled and it's still giving you the same result?

Comment: Yep (Shit, formatting gone bad. Sorry!)

`rotation[0][0] = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));`  
`System.out.println("cos" + angle + ": " + rotation[0][0]);`  

Output:  
`cos90.0: -0.2995153947555356`

Comment: Try `System.out.println("cos(" + Math.toRadians(angle) + "): " + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));`

Comment: Got it working :) The cause was unrelated classpath issues making it *not* compile after your comment haha. Appreciate your help mate.

Answer (score 3):

According to the JavaDoc for [`Math.cos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos-double-), the input needs to be in *radians*, however, you are providing your input in [degrees](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees-double-).

```
System.out.println(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)));
```

Yields

```
6.123233995736766E-17
```

Comment: What is the reason for the non-sensical `toDegrees` in the values of the cosine?

Comment: @LutzL: Probably because of the nature of the result of `pi/2` and the fact that floating point numbers tend to be a bit messy when it comes to binary representation.

Comment: Another user who didn't read documentation and fails to realize that every language uses radians for trigonometric functions: FORTRAN, C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, Python, etc.

Comment: You are transforming the result, not the argument, of the cosine function. (And even in the argument, toDegrees would be wrong.) The argument is the angle, the result is a dimensionless ratio between -1 and 1. There are no radians or degrees in the result of the trigonometric functions.

Comment: @LutzL: Now I understand what you mean and you're right,  thought you where referring to the the result. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Math.cos() takes radians as input, not degrees. You can omit the toDegrees() call:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    // 90° as radians
    double angle = Math.PI /2;

    // cos() takes an radian as parameter
    System.out.println(Math.cos(angle));

    // Converting radian to degrees gives wrong result
    System.out.println(Math.cos(Math.toDegrees(angle)));

    // Or the other way round if you have 90 as input
    System.out.println(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90)));
}
```

Comment: I realised my input is actually degrees (90 etc). So the functions need to be fed values in terms of PI?

Comment: The cos() function is fed with radians (Pi), toRadians() is fed with degrees (°) and toDegrees() is fed with radians (Pi).